# How to use regular expressions properly on a SQL files?

Tags: regex, r

I have a lot of undocumented and uncommented `SQL` queries. I would like to extract some information within the SQL-statements. Particularly, I'm interested in DB-names, table names and if possible column names. The queries have usually the following syntax.

```
SELECT *
FROM mydb.table1 m
   LEFT JOIN mydb.sometable o ON m.id = o.id
   LEFT JOIN mydb.sometable t ON p.id=t.id
   LEFT JOIN otherdb.sometable s ON s.column='test'
```

Usually, the statements involes several DBs and Tables. I would like only extract DBs and Tables with any other information. I thought if whether it is possible to extract first the information which begins after FROM & JOIN & LEFT JOIN. Here its usually `db.table` letters such as o t s correspond already to referenced tables. I suppose they are difficult to capture. What I tried without any success is to use something like:

```
gsub(".*FROM \\s*|WHERE|ORDER|GROUP.*", "", vec)
```

Assuming that each statement ends with WHERE/where or ORDER/order or GROUP... But that doesnt work out as expected.

Comment: So you just need the output to have mydb.table1, mydb.sometable and otherdb.sometable?

Comment: Yes, because of the size/number of DBs it is not possible to use some nice ER-Diagrams. So I thought about to use frequencies of DBs and Tables in order to communicate the whole schema

Comment: Do you have the create statements for the tables?  Is the aim to find out what the names are of all the tables and their column names or is it to find the table names and column names used in particular SQL statements?

Comment: It is not necessary to find the corresponding SQL statements. The most important aspect is to find DBs and Tables which came with the DBs.Its serves as a reference for future queries to find Tables in corresponding DBs because there is no information/schema at all. So the aim is to find out what the names are of all the DBs and their Tables (optionally Columns )

Comment: So are the create statements available?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. They are not available. Just hundreds of SQL-queries as in the example. I have already extracted them into one .txt document.

Comment: I mean they are available I guess. But there are more then 50 DBs containing 40-100 tables each. I would have to go each table with SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name. I mean I dont know an automated way to extract them.

Comment: But I guess I can also get them as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't indicated which database system you are using but virtually all such systems have introspection facilities that would allow you to get this information a lot more easily and reliably than attempting to parse SQL statements.  The following code which supposes SQLite can likely be adapted to your situation by getting a list of your databases and then looping over the databases and using `dbConnect` to connect to each one in turn running code such as this:

```
library(gsubfn)
library(RSQLite)

con <- dbConnect(SQLite()) # use in memory database for testing

# create two tables for purposes of this test
dbWriteTable(con, "BOD", BOD, row.names = FALSE)
dbWriteTable(con, "iris", iris, row.names = FALSE)

# get all table names and columns
tabinfo <- Map(function(tab) names(fn$dbGetQuery(con, "select * from $tab limit 0")),
      dbListTables(con))

dbDisconnect(con)
```

giving an R list whose names are the table names and whose entries are the column names:

```
> tabinfo
$BOD
[1] "Time"   "demand"

$iris
[1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species"
```

or perhaps long form output is preferred:

```
setNames(stack(tabinfo), c("column", "table"))
```

giving:

```
        column table
1         Time   BOD
2       demand   BOD
3 Sepal.Length  iris
4  Sepal.Width  iris
5 Petal.Length  iris
6  Petal.Width  iris
7      Species  iris
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the stringi package for this.

```
library(stringi)

# Your string vector

myString <- "SELECT * 
FROM mydb.table1 m 
LEFT JOIN mydb.sometable o ON m.id = o.id 
LEFT JOIN mydb.sometable t ON p.id=t.id 
LEFT JOIN otherdb.sometable s ON s.column='test'"

# Three stringi functions used
# stringi_extract_all_regex will extract the strings which have FROM or JOIN followed by some text till the next space
# string_replace_all_regex will replace all the FROM or JOIN followed by space with null string
# stringi_unique will extract all unique strings

t <- stri_unique(stri_replace_all_regex(stri_extract_all_regex(myString, "((FROM|JOIN) [^\\s]+)", simplify = TRUE), 
                       "(FROM|JOIN) ", ""))
> t
[1] "mydb.table1"       "mydb.sometable"    "otherdb.sometable"
```